# MongoDB indexes are not being used

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have created a compound index:

```
db.installedbase.createIndex({serviceline_id:1, product:"text"})
```

However found that index is not being used while hitting `find()`

```
db.installedbase.find({serviceline_id:601.0}).explain()
```

Output:

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "entitlements.installedbase",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "serviceline_id" : {
            "$eq" : 601.0
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
            "serviceline_id" : {
                "$eq" : 601.0
            }
        },
        "direction" : "forward"
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "CHNMCT136701L",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.6.3",
    "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
},
"ok" : 1.0
}
```

And text search:

```
db.installedbase.find({product:"network_router"}).explain()
```

Output:

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "entitlements.installedbase",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "product" : {
            "$eq" : "network_router"
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
            "product" : {
                "$eq" : "network_router"
            }
        },
        "direction" : "forward"
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "CHNMCT136701L",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.6.3",
    "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
},
"ok" : 1.0
}
```

The index is expected to be used as per the docs here: [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/), except for the text index where it may be used only in the case of a text search `$text`. Am I wrong here? Why isn't index used in my case?

Sample data:

```
{
 "_id" : 801.0,
 "serviceline_id" : 601.0,
 "product" : "network_router"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't use an index like this.

You must to create a two separated indexes instead of this one.

Take a look into the [Text Indexs documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text).

> **Compound Index**
>
> A compound index can include a text index key in
>   combination with ascending/descending index keys. However, these
>   compound indexes have the following restrictions:
>
> A compound text index cannot include any other special index types,
>   such as multi-key or geospatial index fields. If the compound text
>   index includes keys preceding the text index key, to perform a $text
>   search, the query predicate must include equality match conditions on
>   the preceding keys. When creating a compound text index, all text
>   index keys must be listed adjacently in the index specification
>   document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index

Comment: So, as per the notes, I have included a match condition for preceding key, that is just a normal index type:`db.installedbase.find({$or:[{serviceline_id:601.0},{product:"network_router"}]}).explain()` , still it isnt taking index into consideration. why?